# Magento connect's order delivery date extension disable required dates

Tags: php, jquery, magento, date

I used Magento connects Order Delivery Date extension to allow the buyer to set the date, when they should receive the goods. Now i want to disable some dates on the calendar that shows at checkout page. Can i use general JQuery calendar date disable at this point? If i can not what is the way it should be done? Any helps would be appreciated.

Comment: it is already in feature list, you should check with user guide first.
http://amasty.com/delivery-date.html

Comment: Yes dev. But i want to disable some more days like independence day and some religion days. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: than you might need some code level customization. because if you make just js related changes than there are possibilities to by pass it